# Use Spring Boot Entity inside Projection Class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have an Entity TableA and an additional Value id like to return in a projection.

If I want to achieve the following setup:

```
public interface MyProjection{
   
    public TableA getTableA();
    public double additionalValue();

}
```

how do I achieve that? Simply going with what I described doesn't work. It returns an error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot project org.postgresql.util.PGobject to server.tables.ClubAddress; Target type is not an interface and no matching Converter found (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->jdk.proxy2.$Proxy180["club_address"])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Referencing an Entity from another Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452220/referencing-an-entity-from-another-entity)

Comment: @Krithick S no, because if i make the proejction an entity it creates a table for it which isnt what i want. Projections arent entitys.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. If you have a running transaction, TableA will be managed by Hibernate and changes to TableA may result in updates

Comment: Whats the best approach to get a JPA Result off a NativeQuery then? There must be a convenient way

Answer (score 0):

The methods are missing implementations. Did you also try with interface based projections like below.

```
public interface MyProjection{
    public TableA getTableA();
    public double additionalValue();
}
```

Comment: Thats a mistake in my originial post, I had already created an Projection interface. I edited it